# Create nested dict from list with custom mapping

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list like below `word_list`:

```
[
 [{'bottom': Decimal('58.650'),
   'text': 'Hi there!',
   'top': Decimal('40.359'),
   'x0': Decimal('21.600'),
   'x1': Decimal('65.644')}
 ],
 [{'bottom': Decimal('74.101'),
   'text': 'Your email',
   'top': Decimal('37.519'),
   'x0': Decimal('223.560'),
   'x1': Decimal('300')},
  {'bottom': Decimal('77.280'),
   'text': 'my@domain.com',
   'top': Decimal('62.506'),
   'x0': Decimal('21.600'),
   'x1': Decimal('140.775')}]
]
```

As you can see, above consists of a list, with what looks like a nested list. The `text` of the above can be represented:

```
[0] = 'Hi there!'
[1] = 'Your Email'
[1] = 'my@domain.com'
```

This is my code, that generates the `row_list`:

```
word_list = sorted(first_page.extract_words(),
                    key=lambda x: x['bottom'])
threshold = float('10')
current_row = [word_list[0], ]
row_list = [current_row, ]

for word in word_list[1:]:
    if abs(current_row[-1]['bottom'] - word['bottom']) <= threshold:
        # distance is small, use same row
        current_row.append(word)
    else:
        # distance is big, create new row
        current_row = [word, ]
        row_list.append(current_row)
```

What I am trying to do, is to map the output of above to something like:

```
new = {
       1: {
          1: {'text': 'Hi there!', 'x0': Decimal('21.600')}
       },
       2: {
          1: {'text':'Your email', 'x0': Decimal('223.560')},
          2: {'text': 'my@domain.com', 'x0': Decimal('21.600')}
       }
      }
```

I have tried all sorts of things, and just can't figure it out - as my original `word_list` is a list, and I am trying to show it as a dict...

Comment: the posted expected result does not  correlate much with any "threshold". It's a simple mapping

Comment: But the sorting and threshold have to be applied to the list, and then after I need to map the values.

Comment: Can you clarify the sorting you want? You don't mention it in the text, but it's in your code and since the desired output seems to be sorted the same as the input it's not clear if it matters.

Comment: The sorting only matters in the first loop (the code that I posted), since I use it to check against a threshold. The `row_list` is sorted but don’t need to be in the final format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For succinct code with reliable input, you can use a short recursive function. This will work with multiple levels of nesting (if that's needed):

```
def nest(l):
    if not isinstance(l, list):
        return {'text': l['text'], 'x0': l['x0']}
    return {i+1:nest(v) for i,v in enumerate(l)}
```

With your input, it returns:

```
> pp.pprint(nest(l))

> { 1: {1: {'text': 'Hi there!', 'x0': Decimal('21.600')}},
    2: {1: {'text': 'Your email', 'x0': Decimal('223.560')},
        2: {'text': 'my@domain.com', 'x0': Decimal('21.600')}
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The could be onelined but it would be nasty:

```
result = {}
for index in range(len(l)):
    append = {}
    for index2 in range(len(l[index])):
        append[index2 + 1] = {key: val for key, val in l[index][index2].items() if key in ('x0', 'text')}
    result[index + 1] = append

#result = {index + 1: {index2:  for index in range(len(l))}

import json
print(json.dumps(result, indent=2))
```

Output:

```
{
  "1": {
    "1": {
      "text": "Hi there!",
      "x0": "21.600"
    }
  },
  "2": {
    "1": {
      "text": "Your email",
      "x0": "223.560"
    },
    "2": {
      "text": "my@domain.com",
      "x0": "21.600"
    }
  }
}
```

Note that it prints the keys as strings but they are actually `int`s. The `json.dumps(...)`, which I use to print it nicely, turned them to strings.

The one-liner:

```
result = {index + 1: {index2 + 1: {key: val for key, val in l[index][index2].items() if key in ('x0', 'text')} for index2 in range(len(l[index]))} for index in range(len(l))}
```

Comment: Just curious - why is it nasty?

Comment: Extremely unreadable. I will add it to the end of the question.

Comment: @oliverbj Added